# How to read the files sequentially from a subfolder in document directory of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, saving-data, data-retrieval

I am saving some images in to the documents directory of the app using the following code.

```
for (int k=0;k<[_imageNames count];k++)
{
    NSString *imagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",k]];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([_imageNames objectAtIndex:k], 1.0f);
    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Now I am trying to load the images sequentially into an NSMutableArray.
Can someone point me towards the right direction.

Comment: What is the question?  Do you not know how to load files?  How to add objects to arrays?  Something else?

Comment: @Javy Yes Ofcourse i know how to load files. But i wanted to know if there is a way to get the number of files inside a folder so that i can do an iteration to add the objects to an NSMutablearray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the name of the file, iterating through and checking if the file exists:

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]`

When it returns NO then you know there are no more files to add.

Comment: Oops it was that easy..... Sometimes the answer is infront of your eyes and you dont see it... Thanks a lot Javy